Symmetric positive definite matrix - submatrices
Let $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$ be two fixed positive numbers and let $A$ be a symmetric real matrix with $\lambda |x|^2 \leq (Ax,x) \leq \Lambda |x|^2$.
Let $B$ be a matrix derived from $A$ as follows: $B$ retains the diagonal entries of $A$ and one off diagonal entry. An example would be $B$ having the diagonal and one above and below the diagonal entries from $A$ and the rest to be $0$.
Another example would be $B$ having diagonal and two above and below the diagonal entries from $A$.
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}a_{11} & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
                              0 & a_{22} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
                              \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                              0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{nn}
 \end{array} \right), \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
                              a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \ldots & 0 \\
                              \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                              0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{nn}
 \end{array} \right), \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}a_{11} & 0 & a_{13} & \ldots & 0\\
                              0 & a_{22} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
                              a_{31} & 0 & a_{33} & \ldots & 0\\
                              \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
                              0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{nn}
 \end{array} \right)
$$
A bunch of such matrices can be constructed and are clearly symmetric. Is it also true that these matrices satisfy bounds of the form $\lambda |x|^2 \leq (Ax,x) \leq \Lambda |x|^2$ with the same $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$?  Clearly the diagonal matrix does, but what about the others?

To be clear, the details here matter a lot. Iosif Pinelis's answer shows that the answer is "no" if you can retain 2 or more non-zero off-diagonal entries above the diagonal (like in your second example?). But if you can only retain 1 non-zero off-diagonal entry (as specified in your text?) then you just have a bunch of $2 \times 2$ and $1 \times 1$ blocks on the diagonal, so the answer is "yes" (by pinching/interlacing inequalities or something like that).

I was specifically looking for matrices that retain both the bounds and symmetry. Are there other possibilities besides the diagonal matrix that can preserve both?

A counterexample:
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & 4 & -4 \\
 4 & 6 & -5 \\
 -4 & -5 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad
B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & 4 & 0 \\
 4 & 6 & -5 \\
 0 & -5 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
Then $A$ is positive definite but $B$ is not.
